# Joining table to a near table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, proximity

I calculated the distances between one set of xy coordinates and another set of xy coordinates.

So my near table has the ID variables, distance and rank.

However, when I join the near table to the csv file containing the xy coordinates, I lose all ranks that are not = 1. It only joins the closest distance.

How do I modify the joining process to include all distances and ranks?

Comment: A join is one-to-one, it's not the first rank but rather the first match in the destination table. If you want to see *all* matches for sorceID to destIDs you will need to use a relate or switch it around and join your near table to your source points... you can make this spatial with coincident points by creating an XY Event Layer in ArcMap http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000

Answer (score 1):

The [Make Query Table tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006r000000) does this.  However, you probably have to convert everything to a file geodatabase (I will never work with a shapefile and cvs file due to severe limitations affecting most analysis tools and horrible performance unless they are extremely small) and any points that are not matched by a table record will disappear, the layer cannot be edited, and performance is bad in my opinion.

If you have ArcGIS 10.1 or above you should convert the shapefile and cvs file to a real table in a file geodatabase, do the join normally to the feature class in the file geodatabase and export the data.  The export will cause every joined feature to actually be generated as a real point feature with all attributes combined permanently for every table record associated with every point.  This only works if both are in the same geodatabase.

Anyway, you have not said what you will do with the points, so there could be other better approaches.  For example, if this is for labels you could try my approach in [this Blog post](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2015/02/07/creating-labels-with-related-table-data).  A relate will work for the identify tool if you don't mind expanding the relate tree (I do mind, so I don't do that often).  If you need summaries they can work for a join to see each record if the summary boils down to a one-to-one relationship.